# PHP file_get_contents not working with file onedrive (403 FORBIDDEN)

Tags: php, symfony, file-get-contents, onedrive, http-status-code-403

I have a web application with symfony 2.8 and i using Microsoft one drive to save my files. since December 2015 the function below work perfectly :

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request, File $file)
        {
               //RemotePAth : "https://entreprise-my.sharepoint.com/personal/admininfo/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=xxxxxx&authkey=xxxxxxxxxx"
               //MimeType :"application/pdf"
                return new Response(file_get_contents($file->getRemotePath()), 200, array('Content-Type' => $file->getMimeType(), 'charset' => 'UTF-8'));

        }
```

now this function return always "**failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN**"

On onedrive the file is public to everyone.

Note: Before when I open the remotepath on navigator the file is downloaded automatically. now, it's redirect to onother Url and open file

Comment: CORS? I know with AWS S3 that can sometimes be an issue

Comment: thanks for your comment, can you explain to me how it is resolved with AWS S3